# web page loaded through wx.html2.WebView not having direct print

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

`html2.webview` object supports `print` method, it opens a print preview dialog with default print page setup.

I need a direct print with the print page setup loaded through script (without going through print preview dialog.  How can I accomplish this?  My current code is as follows:

```
import wx.html2 as webview

self.wv = webview.WebView.New(self)

self.wv.Print()
```

if direct print not possible, i need the print page setup (configurint A4 page, portrait, margins, heater, footer)